# Save multiple objects using saveRDS and lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I'm trying to write function that can take objects and save them each individually. This is what I have so far:

```
# Objects
x = 1:10
y = letters[1:10]
# Save location
folder = "Output_Data"

# Save a single object
ObjSave <- function(object, folder) {
  filename = paste0(folder, "/", deparse(substitute(object)), ".rds")
  saveRDS(object, filename)
}
ObjSave(x, folder)  # Works fine. Output: x.rds

# Save multiple objects
ObjSave <- function(..., folder) {
  invisible(lapply(
    list(...),
    function(object) {
    filename = paste0(folder, "/", deparse(substitute(object)), ".rds")
    saveRDS(object, filename)}
  ))
}
ObjSave(x, y, folder = folder)
# Creates a single object "X[[i]].rds"
# When I use readRDS, it gives the last object i.e. y
# I'm trying to get separate x.rds and y.rds containing x and y respectively
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I think it's just the `deparse(substitute(object))` that is giving me issues, but I haven't worked it out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful when you deparse an object.

If you're looking for the variable name in the function input, it'd be easiest to do it on the first line in the function, otherwise if you call it later after changing how it's referenced (e.g., in the lapply loop) the parse tree changes, and therefore the deparse name changes.

```
x = 1:10
y = letters[1:10]
# Save location
folder = "output_data"

# Save multiple objects
ObjSave <- function(..., folder) {
    objects <- list(...)
    object_names <- sapply(substitute(list(...))[-1], deparse)
    sapply(1:length(objects), function(i) {
        filename = paste0(folder, "/", object_names[i], ".rds")
        saveRDS(objects[i], filename)
    })
}
ObjSave(x, y, folder = folder)
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was after! Thanks :)